# Navigation to another screen is always blank in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another using the `Navigator.push()`. I have a `GridView` and onTap of any `GridTile` I am opening another screen. But the second screen is always blank even though there is a `Scaffold`. There is no problem with the networking call as all the data from the network is getting loaded correctly. I verified by printing them. Here are the two screens:

First screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/item_model.dart';
import '../blocs/movies_bloc.dart';
import 'movie_detail.dart';

class MovieList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MovieListState();
  }
}

class MovieListState extends State<MovieList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("initState called");
    bloc.fetchAllMovies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    bloc.dispose();
    print("dispose called");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Popular Movies'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.allMovies,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return buildList(snapshot);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GridTile(
            child: InkResponse(
              enableFeedback: true,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${snapshot.data
                    .results[index].poster_path}',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              onTap: () => openDetailPage(snapshot.data, index),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  openDetailPage(ItemModel data, int index) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        MovieDetail(
          title: data.results[index].title,
          posterUrl: data.results[index].poster_path,
          description: data.results[index].overview,
          releaseDate: data.results[index].release_date,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Second screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MovieDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final posterUrl;
  final description;
  final releaseDate;
  final String title;

  MovieDetail({Key key, this.title, this.posterUrl, this.description, this.releaseDate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Movie Details'),
      ),
      body: Text(
        "Sample text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you printing "Sample text" in white on a white background? Is that your problem?

Comment: No. Everything is black. I cant even see anything drawn in screen. @RémiRousselet

Comment: Oh, found it. I'll add an answer

Comment: Waiting for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with the builder of your `MaterialPageRoute`: It doesn't return anything.

Add a return statement and it should be fine:

```
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return MovieDetail(
      title: data.results[index].title,
      posterUrl: data.results[index].poster_path,
      description: data.results[index].overview,
      releaseDate: data.results[index].release_date,
    );
  }),
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed now after seeing my mistake. Anyway thanks for saving my day :)